# Laravel 8: Which is the correct way to use subqueries with the ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in play for this query.

First one is `forecasts` this contains user's forecast on several games, the most important fields are: `user_id`, `game_id` and `userscore`

Then there's `games` table which contains `game_id`, `week` and `realscore`

I'm oversimplifying, but that's the idea. In the `games` I have all the games that will be played on a given week.

Now, I want to get all the games forecasted by the user on certain week, I have already solved this using `DB::` but I think should be a better way only using the ORM, so this is what I tried:

```
$fore = Forecast::where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->addSelect(['game_id' => Game::select('id')
        ->where('week', $week)
        ->whereColumn('game_id', 'games.id')
    ])
    ->get();
```

Now my problem is this solution is basically ignoring `->where('week', $week)`, if I leave or take this line, it is giving me 11 records (I have 6 games forecasted for week 1, and 5 games forecasted for week 2, everything is test data).

I tried with `select()` instead of `addSelect()` and see no diference.

So, what am I doing wrong? Do I have to use a subquery and a `whereIn()`?

Comment: What are the data types for the `$week` vs the column of `week`? Also try putting the `select` part of the query before the first `where` clause. In addition, if you could share the raw SQL produced it might help you debug. To see that just change the `->get()` to `->toSql()` and `dd` the variable `$fore`.

Comment: `$week` is an integer, which is the type of data in the `week` column. Thanks on the `->toSql()` tip, I was wondering on how to know the SQL produced

Comment: Can you share the SQL query produced so that we can solve your issue?